# Shader execution stops in vertex shader before pixel shader

Tags: xna, shader

I’m trying to store the depth information of model in XNA from the lights point of view. The model renders fine using a normal shader.

This is the shader code

```
float4x4 xShadowMapLight;


///DEPTH MAP

float4 RenderShadowMapPS( VS_SHADOW_OUTPUT In ) : COLOR
{ 

    return float4(1,0,0,0); //In.Depth.x,In.Depth.x,In.Depth.x,0);
}

VS_SHADOW_OUTPUT RenderShadowMapVS(float4 vPos: POSITION)
{
  VS_SHADOW_OUTPUT Out;

  Out.Position = mul(vPos, xShadowMapLight);

  Out.Depth.x = 1-(Out.Position.z/Out.Position.w);    
  return Out;
}


technique ToonShaderDepthMap
{

pass P0
{

    VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 RenderShadowMapVS(); 
    PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 RenderShadowMapPS();
}

}
```

And this is the way I generate the light matrix that is passed to the shader.

```
Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(modelTransform.Translation, new Vector3(0, 500, 75), Vector3.Up);
Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, 1.0f, (float)globals.NEAR_PLANE, (float)globals.FAR_PLANE);
Matrix ShadowMapLight = modelTransform * view * projection;
```

But apparently I’m not always getting to the pixel shader and it stops in the vertex for some reason.
(I have modified the pixel shader to output always a red pixel, so I know when it goes through).

`xShadowMapLight` is the `Matrix` containing all the transformations from the lights point of view.
Apparently the problem is in `mul(vPos, xShadowMapLight);` cause if I change the matrix for an `Identity` one the shader gets to the pixel one.

Any idea why this might happen?

Thanks in advance,
Walfrido.

Comment: There's only one reason that the pixel shader wouldn't run:  the rasterizer thinks that the pixel falls outside of the viewport.  In your example, what values do `NEAR_PLANE`, `FAR_PLANE`, and `modelTransform.Translation` have?  My psychic debugging powers tell me that your model may be clipping the near plane.